# Access VBA select statement to count # of true has syntax error. What to change?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access VBA I am trying to count the number of "true" in a boolean column (called "1Pas") and declare that number as a variable that I can use later in the code. Table is called "tbl_Avail".

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Private Sub BtnRun_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strPrio1 As String
Dim strPrio2 As String
Dim strPrio3 As String
Dim strPrio1Req As Long
Dim StudentsMiss As Long
Dim StudentsTotal As Long

Set db = CurrentDb

'Find Studentstotal
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Abs(Sum(1Pas)) As Total FROM tbl_Avail WHERE 1Pas = true;")
StudentsTotal = rs!Total
```

I get a run-time error 3075, syntax error, missing operator in expression "Abs(Sum(1Pas))".

The table only contains this column and my expected result would be an integer, lets say 14, and that the variable StudentsTotal would be set to this number, so I can use it later.

Clearly I am doing something very wrong, so I would very much appreciate any solutions to the above that can help me along. Thank you!

Peter

Comment: I think you can use simply `DCount()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using Count vs Sum.

```
'Find Studentstotal
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(*) AS StudentTotal FROM tbl_Avail WHERE (((tbl_Avail.1Pas)=True));")
StudentsTotal = rs!StudentTotal
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried it, and the syntax error moves to (((tbl_Avail.1Pas)=True))

Comment: Don't know what is causing the error on your dataset. It worked correctly on my data set as: SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 FROM Owners WHERE (((Owners.EMailDocs)=True));. Could you post a screen capture of the error? Although I can't find a prohibition against starting a field name with a number in Access, I've always been told that it is bad practice, but I can't say that it is what is causing the error.

Comment: I suspect you are correct:-) Just tried to rename column "1Pas" to "Pas1" instead, and then it worked. I was not aware that a column can not start with a number, but now I know. Thank you!